# Index OutOfBoundsException in Android

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, indexoutofboundsexception

OnCreateView Method

```
ListView usersList;
TextView noUsersText;
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
int totalUsers = 0;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialogue;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);

    usersList = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.usersList);
    noUsersText = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.noUsersText);

    mProgressDialogue = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    mProgressDialogue.setMessage("Loading...");
    mProgressDialogue.show();

    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Users");
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.usersList);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, arrayList);
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String name = ds.child("Name").getValue().toString();
//                    Log.d("TAG", name);
                arrayList.add(name);
            }
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please Check Your Internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

    usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            UserDetails.chatWith = al.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Chat.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

UserDetails

```
public class UserDetails {
static String phonenumber = "";
static String chatWith = "";
}
```

I'm still a beginner. Just trying out a simple chat application which uses phone number for authentication. the registering and logging in seems fine. Even updating the users profile is fine. then i get to this fragment which shows the users the list of contacts using the app. This fragment successfully fetches the list of name from the database and shows it, but when the user clicks on one of the names, its showing an exception. The user should be taken to the chat.class where he will be able to chat with other people(hopefully)
please help... 
Showing and IndexOUtOfBounds exception in the line UserDetails.chatWith = al.get(Position)
Invalid Index 0, size is 0

Comment: show your logcat and dont set adapter in onDataChange

Comment: Where did you define "al"? Some Code is missing.

Comment: Hey Courtney, We need info on `UserDetails` class as well as what the `al` variable is. Please provide more code.

Comment: Please look to the edited one

Comment: @CourtneyMiller you are not adding elements to `al` so its size is 0

Comment: So what should i change

Comment: @CourtneyMiller you are updating _arrayList_ in `onDataChange` so you can use that instead of  _al_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your data to al, not a new ArrayList like this:

```
@Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.usersList);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, al);
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String name = ds.child("Name").getValue().toString();
//                    Log.d("TAG", name);
                al.add(name);
            }
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *al* or *arrayList* and one more suggestion, don't initialize/set adapter in `onDataChange`. You can initialize or set it in `onCreateView` and notify it from `onDataChange` like below:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);

    usersList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.usersList);
    noUsersText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.noUsersText);

    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.usersList);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, arrayList);

    mProgressDialogue = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    mProgressDialogue.setMessage("Loading...");
    mProgressDialogue.show();

    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("Users");
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String name = ds.child("Name").getValue().toString();
//              Log.d("TAG", name);
                arrayList.add(name);
                // or al.add(name);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Check Your Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    usersRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

    usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            UserDetails.chatWith = arrayList.get(position);
            //UserDetails.chatWith = al.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Chat.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Tysm... sorry still a beginner